# How do I enable auth on postman?

Tags: laravel, postman

I am trying to test an API from a website built with Laravel 4.2 using Postman.

The problem is that every request returns "Forbidden!", which makes sense given that I did not provide it any authentication details. The question is, where do I put them? Basic Auth does not seem to work.

Comment: It depends on what kind of authentication the server-side application is using.

Comment: @ADyson where do I find that?

Comment: Probably by examining the application's settings and/or code. Since you mentioned it's Laravel 4, the [security documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) for that framework is likely to be a good starting point for understanding it.

Comment: I'd also assume that [someone has done this task before](https://www.google.com/search?q=postman+authentication+with+laravel) and you might be be able to look up what people have done in Postman already to set authentication parameters.

Comment: @ADyson After completing the medium post, it still does not work, I get redirected to the login page, stating that the email and password fields must not be empty.

Comment: How you do this depends on the way you are authenticating. For web authentication (e.g. using cookies) an approach that works is installing the postman interceptor browser extension and log in via the browser. That way postman will have working session cookies that it can send. You don't need to do that, you can also just copy paste the session cookie from your browser to postman. If you are using token authentication it is easier since you only need to add a working token to the authentication header (in both these scenarios the assumption is you are able to provide the token/cookie)

Comment: `After completing the medium post, it still does not work`...perhaps you're not using the same auth scheme then, or perhaps you applied some aspect of the advice incorrectly. It's impossible to tell, as you've provided no details either of your laravel setup, or what specifics you're doing in postman. We'd need a [mre]. As above, there are potentially different schemes in place. All we can do is direct you to existing resources online about this topic in general, ultimately you'll have to discover what the application is expecting you to do, and then implement it.